# Show that an invertible holomorphic function must be a rotation if it satisfies these conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f(z)$ be an invertible holomorphic mapping of the unit disc to itself, such that $f(0)=0$. Show that $f(z)=\lambda z$ for some $\lambda$, such that $|\lambda|=1$.

I considered using Schwarz lemma. And the aim is to show that there exists $0<|z|<1$, such that $|f(z)|=|z|$. But I have a hard time figuring out how to use the condition that $f$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since $f$ is invertible, it has an inverse $g = f^{-1}$. Both $f$ and $g$ are then holomorphic maps from the unit disc to itself, and also $f(0) = 0$ and $g(0) = 0$. Suppose that $|f(z)| < |z|$ for some $z$. Then $|g(f(z))| > |f(z)|$, right? Can that happen?